# random binary of one million bit file size

Tags: c#, binary

I want to generate a one million bit random binary but my problem is that the code take to much time and not execute why that happen?

```
string result1 = "";

  Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {

            result1 += ((rand.Next() % 2 == 0) ? "0" : "1");

        }

         textBox1.Text = result1.ToString();
```

Comment: This is likely due to the costs of the many, many, many string concatenations going on. Using a StringBuilder and appending the "0" or "1" gets a result in LINQPad almost immediately on my machine.

Comment: I don't think a textbox is the right place to store a 1-million-character string. What is the end goal?

Comment: You could also call [`NextBytes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextbytes) with a byte array of size 125000 (1,000,000 / 8) and get them in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating strings is an O(N) operation. Strings are immutable, so when you add to a string the new value is copied into a new string, which requires iterating the previous string. Since you're adding a value for each iteration, the amount that has to be read each time grows with each addition, leading to a performance of O(N^2). Since your N is 1,000,000 this takes a very, very long time, and probably is eating all of the memory you have storing these intermediary throw-away strings.

The normal solution when building a string with an arbitrary number of inputs is to instead use a StringBuilder. Although, a 1,000,000 character bit string is still.. unwieldy. Assuming a bitstring is what you want/need, you can change your code to something like the following and have a much more performant solution.

```
public string GetGiantBitString() {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var rand = new Random();
    for(var i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
        sb.Append(rand.Next() % 2);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, it takes about 0.035 seconds on my box:

```
   private static IEnumerable<Byte> MillionBits()
   {
       var rand = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
       //a million bits is 125,000 bytes, so
       var bytes = new List<byte>(125000);
       for (var i = 0; i < 125; ++i)
       {
           byte[] tempBytes = new byte[1000];
           rand.GetBytes(tempBytes);
           bytes.AddRange(tempBytes);
       }

       return bytes;
   }

   private static string BytesAsString(IEnumerable<Byte> bytes)
   {
       var buffer = new StringBuilder();
       foreach (var byt in bytes)
       {
           buffer.Append(Convert.ToString(byt, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
       }

       return buffer.ToString();
   }
```

and then:

```
   var myStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
   myStopWatch.Start();
   var lotsOfBytes = MillionBits();
   var bigString = BytesAsString(lotsOfBytes);
   var len = bigString.Length;
   var elapsed = myStopWatch.Elapsed;
```

The len variable was a million, the string looked like it was all 1s and 0s.

If you really want to fill your textbox full of ones and zeros, just set its `Text` property to `bigString`.